# How to use polygon to create raster landmask in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, masking

I have a shapefile with polygons displaying the borders of the countries of Belgium, The Netherlands, and Luxemburg in EPSG:4326 (WGS 84).

[image]

How can I transform this into a raster landmask, showing values of 1 when inside the border and 0 outside the border? Additionally, the raster should have a 0.01° (~1.5km) resolution, with an extent between 49N-53.75N, 2E-7.5E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Create constant raster layer` from `Menu Processing / Toolbox`, set extent to your vector layer, define pixel size, constant value.
2. `Clip raster by mask layer` from `Menu Raster / Extraction`

[image]
*Remark: my project CRS was set to EPSG:32631 / UTM zone 31N, that's why the shapes have another distortion than yours.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Rasterize (Vector to Raster) tool to convert a polygon layer to raster layer.
`Raster menu > Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`

or in Processing Toolbox it is found in

`GDAL > Vector Conversion > Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`

Steps to use:

1. Select your polygon layer as the `input layer`
2. Enter `fixed value to burn` as 1
3. Choose `output raster size units` as pixels or georeferenced units
4. Choose `horizontal/vertical resolution` of the output .tif
5. Enter `output extents`, use a AOI layer, or draw on canvas
6. Choose to load as temporary layer or choose layer name and save location

This tool has many other options that may be of interest to you.

[image: Rasterize (Vector to Raster) Tool Location and Options]